# x86 - Assembly language encryption/obfuscation - how to reverse?

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, obfuscation

I've been given the following encryption program: what it effectively does is use an EKey var(I) and temp_char var that equals the first, second, third and so on character in the array I'm passing through depending on the iteration of the for loop contained.

I've tried to comment and understand it to the best of my ability.

The following commented values are from looking at the registers/values in 'watch' in visual studio, and is assuming that I enter "aaaa" as my testing string.

Note: EChars is an array that is defined earlier on in the program, but I don't really think it's necessary to mention much about it beyond the fact that it can hold six chars maximum and is terminated with a $.
Same with DChars.

```
void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;                 // Character temporary store

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // Encrypt characters one at a time
{
    temp_char = OChars [i];         // Get the next char from Original Chars array

    __asm {                         
        push   eax                  // Prepare the EAX register to store volatile memory.
        push   ecx                  // Prepare the ECX register to store volatile memory. 
                                    // Removes whatever value is stored in there to start with.
                                    // Pushing pushes the value (not stored in a register necessarily) and writes it into the stack

        movzx  ecx,temp_char        // Moves the char with zeroes, meaning that the temp_char value has 0s at the beginning
        lea    eax,EKey             // Loads the address of the Ekey currently in memory, into the EAX register
        push ecx                    // Push ecx to the top of the stack. Stores char
        push eax                    // Stores address of ekey
        call   encrypt_17           // Calls the encyrption routine below, before jumping back up to the line below
        add esp, 8                  // Adding 8 to the stack pointer moves the pointer to (somewhere in the stack, I'm unsure where)
        mov    temp_char,al         // AL is the last 8 bits of the EAX register, what happens here is that AL is then moved into
                                    // the temp_char value, after it has been encrypted; modifying the value before storing it into the EChars array

        pop    ecx                  // Restore original register values
        pop    eax                  // ""
    }
    EChars [i] = temp_char;         // Store encrypted char in the Encrypted Chars array location depending on loop
}
return;

// Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
//                  ECX = the character to be encrypted (in the low 8-bit field, CL).
// Output: register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character (in the low 8-bit field, AL).



__asm {

   encrypt_17:
           push esi 
           push ecx                //temp char t = 116 first time around
           mov  esi, eax           //sets eax to esi, which has a value of '2422272'
           and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF
           ror byte ptr[esi], 1
           ror byte ptr[esi], 1    //these two lines set Ekey I(72) to Ekey R(82) (inc by 10?)
           add byte ptr[esi], 0x01 //adds 1 to the ekey, changing it to S
           mov ecx, [esi]          //move location of Ekey (S) to ECX
           pop edx                 //restore original val of edx (which appears to be 116 (temp char, t from 'test')
       x17 : 
           ror dl, 1        //dl = t, after this it's set to 58 ':', edx is also set to 58,
                            //second time through sets edx to 29 and dl to 29 '\x1d'
           dec ecx          //decrement ecx to 82 from 83,
           jnz x17          //goes until ecx is 0
           mov eax, edx     //eax gets set to 142. which is 'Z' with an arrow above it
           add eax, 0x20    //eax gets set to 174, from 154
           xor eax, 0xAA    //XOR'ing 154 with AA sets it to 4
           pop esi          //ECX gets set to 0
           ret              //value gets returned
}
```

Below is my attempts at decryption so far:

```
void decrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{   char temp_char;                 // Character temporary store

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)    // Encrypt characters one at a time
{
temp_char = EChars[i];              // Get the next char from Encrypted Chars array

__asm {
        push   eax                  // Prepare the EAX register to store volatile memory.
        push   ecx                  // Prepare the ECX register to store volatile memory. 
                                    // Removes whatever value is stored in there to start with.
                                    // Pushing pushes the value (not stored in a register necessarily) and writes it into the stack

        movzx  ecx, temp_char       // Moves the char with zeroes, meaning that the temp_char value has 0s at the beginning
        lea    eax, EKey            // Loads the address of the Ekey currently in memory, into the EAX register
        push ecx                    // Push ecx to the top of the stack. Stores char
        push eax                    // Stores address of ekey
        call   decrypt_17           // Calls the encyrption routine below, before jumping back up to the line below
        add esp, 8                  // Adding 8 to the stack pointer moves the pointer to...
        mov    temp_char, al        // AL is the last 8 bits of the EAX register, what happens here is that AL is then moved into
                                    // the temp_char value, after it has been encrypted; modifying the value before storing it into the EChars array

        pop    ecx                  // Restore original register values
        pop    eax                  // ""
    }
DChars[i] = temp_char;              // Store decrypted char
}
return;

// Inputs: register EAX = 32-bit address of Ekey,
//                  ECX = the character to be encrypted (in the low 8-bit field, CL).
// Output: register EAX = the encrypted value of the source character (in the low 8-bit field, AL).

__asm {

decrypt_17:

        push ebp                    
        mov ebp, esp                

        mov ecx, [ebp + 12]         // The base pointer is moved to the location of EKey -- Ekey is moved into ECX
        mov eax, [ebp + 8]          // Base pointer points to Ekey address

        push esi                    // Push ESI to the top of the stack, ready for storing the EKey value later on in the mov esi, eax line
        push ecx                    // Push ECX to the top  of the stack, in this program our ECX register holds the variable temp_char

        mov  esi, eax               // Copy the register (EAX) that the address of Ekey is stored in, into ESI
                                    // Gets EKey

        and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF    // AND the address in ESI which contains the Ekey with FF in hex

        rol byte ptr[esi], 2        // Revert the two rotate right with carry operations

        sub byte ptr[esi], 0x01     // The byte ptr implies that the operand size is 8-bits in value; subbing 1 in hex is the opposite of adding

        mov ecx, [esi]              
        pop edx                     // Get temp_char

x17 :   rol al, 1                   // Revert the rotate right op
                                    // carry loops back around to the most-significant bit of the value

        inc ecx                     // Here is where I'm having issues with the reversal... I don't know when to stop decrementing 
        cmp ecx, 0x52
        jle x17                     
        mov eax, edx                // ***The modifed temp_char value stored in EDX is then moved into the EKey register
        sub eax, 0x20               
        xor eax, 0xAA               

        pop esi                     // Restoring the value on top of the stack, in this case the modified temp_char value to the top of the stack ready for the next call

        mov ebp, esp                // Resetting the first instruction; Base Pointer val
        pop ebp                     // Return original EBP value
        ret                         // Return the encrypted value, stored in EAX/AL to the calling function
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried to comment and understand it to the best of my ability.

Sorry to be blunt, but not good enough to write decoder, would be pure accident.

I will comment on some things, but there's probably too much to catch it all...

```
        push   eax                  // Prepare the EAX register to store volatile memory.
        push   ecx                  // Prepare the ECX register to store volatile memory.
```

(1) "stack memory" is ordinary memory, but for convenience the pair of registers `ss:esp` points to the imaginary "top of the stack", and it grows toward lower addresses. Ie. `push eax` can be viewed as `esp = esp - 4; [esp] = eax;`, writing the value into memory, and updating `esp` to point to it. `pop` is reversing this, loading values from `[esp]` and updating `esp += 4;` to "release the value from stack".

```
        push ecx                    // Push ecx to the top of the stack. Stores char
        push eax                    // Stores address of ekey
        call   encrypt_17           // Calls the encyrption routine below, before jumping back up to the line below
        add esp, 8                  // Adding 8 to the stack pointer moves the pointer to (somewhere in the stack, I'm unsure where)
```

Not sure why they put the char + EChar address at stack, when they don't use them at all (the `encrypt_17` is taking the values from registers, not from stack), probably just to add to confusion. Anyway, as the two `push` are using 32 bit (== 4 bytes) values, that means that `add esp,8` will "throw away" both of them (check (1) again or watch in debugger), restoring stack into the state ahead of this part of code and the final restoring of original `eax/ecx` will then work correctly. BTW the `encrypt_17` does modify also `edx`, which is not restored, so this inline assembly works (by luck) only when compiler does not need `edx` preserved for the C code.

```
   encrypt_17:
           push esi 
           push ecx                //temp char t = 116 first time around
           mov  esi, eax           //sets eax to esi, which has a value of '2422272'
```

Stores into stack (at the top at this moment is return address to the code above for `ret` instruction) old `esi`, and the char to encode (in `ecx`), then sets `esi` to `eax` (`esi = EChar address;`), not eax to esi.

```
           and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF
           ror byte ptr[esi], 1
           ror byte ptr[esi], 1    //these two lines set Ekey I(72) to Ekey R(82) (inc by 10?)
           add byte ptr[esi], 0x01 //adds 1 to the ekey, changing it to S
```

Is this some kind of joke? Can't you really be bothered to read Intel instruction reference guide to know what `ror` does? (those values in comments must be wrong, I is not 72, and rotating 72 twice to right will be not 82, neither in decimal, or in hexadecimal (not clear, which one you are using)).

```
           mov ecx, [esi]          //move location of Ekey (S) to ECX
           pop edx                 //restore original val of edx (which appears to be 116 (temp char, t from 'test')
```

Loads the modified EChar[0] value to `cl` (upper 24 bits are zeroed by the first `and dword`, so `ecx` is read, but only low 8 bits are interesting. And then `pop edx` will pop last value stored in stack to `edx`. The last values was original `ecx` (char to encrypt). See (1) again to realize the `push/pop` pairing is not fixed on the register, but it depends on the order of `push/pop` instruction, which value is stored/loaded from/to which register. The same effect could have been achieved without stack by doing `mov edx,ecx` at the beginning of `encrypt_17`.

```
           ror dl, 1        //dl = t, after this it's set to 58 ':', edx is also set to 58,
```

`edx` and `dl` is the same register, so of course both are `58`. The difference is, that `edx` is full 32 bits, while `dl` is the lowest 8 bit part of it, which can be used separately by using `dl` alias. And the `ror` is done only on the low 8 bit part, so any bit leaving on right from b0 will re-enter into b7 of `edx`, not b31. That would require `ror edx,1` (to rotate all 32 bits). You can also access separately bits b8-b15 by alias `dh`, and bits b0-b15 by alias `dx`. And the whole `edx` is low 32 bit part alias of `rdx` on 64b CPUs.

```
           mov eax, edx     //eax gets set to 142. which is 'Z' with an arrow above it
           add eax, 0x20    //eax gets set to 174, from 154
```

First you say `eax` is 142, then suddenly it was 154? As 0x20 is 32, it's clear it was 142 (142+32=174). Pay attention which values are displayed in hexa formatting, don't mix 0x20 with 20 decimal.

```
           xor eax, 0xAA    //XOR'ing 154 with AA sets it to 4
```

Not even sure why you display decimal values in this case (and it was 174, not 154), as for example doing `xor` with `0xAA` against `0xAE` is easy to see in head particular bits, how it will end as `0x04`. While in decimal you can't "see" bits, you would have to convert it to binary/hexa first to be able to do the `xor` calculation in head.

```
           pop esi          //ECX gets set to 0
           ret              //value gets returned
```

This restores old `esi`, nothing on `ecx` is changed. Also the stack points after `pop` again at the return address (all local mess cleaned up), so the `ret` will work. If you would forget some `push` on stack, the `ret` would use wrong value as returning address, causing probably crash.

So the encryption does mostly rotate the bits many times (uselessly, as every 8th rotation you get the original value, so only modulo 8 of rotations has some effect), with some adding and xoring, all of that reversible in straightforward way.

The interesting thing to note is, that only first byte of EKey is used, next three are set to zero, and remaining are ignored. So this is 8 bit key strong encryption ... eee... "strong".

---

About reversal:

1) EKey is not "reversed", keep the calculation same as encrypt to have the same value in EKey for decryption.

2) decrypt char backwards, starting with last op (`xor`) etc...

3) you don't need to increase the `ecx` counter up till unknown value, you do the loop the same number of times like encrypt did (from [esi] to 0), but instead of `ror` you do `rol`, that's what reversing the effect of encryption into decryption.

So basically EKey related things are intact (done in same way as encrypt) and the result is number of rotations (same for encryption/decryption, because you reverse rotation direction to undo it). The char itself operations are reversed in order and operation logic. Ie. `xor 0xAA` is reversed by `xor 0xAA` (yes, identical one), but `ror` is reversed by `rol`, `add` by `sub` (or negative value), etc.

Comment: the bluntness is appreciated, don't worry about it.


My comments on this one were different from my actual program, I just quickly went through and wrote through values; didn't understand they weren't very useful so my bad. I'm aware what things like `rol` do and the like.

Really helpful answer, thanks a ton. We managed to reverse my friend's encryption, but he didn't have a jnz unlike in my statement. What I've tried so far is:

`x17:`
`rol dl, 1`
`dec ecx`

`jnz x17`
`mov eax, edx`
`sub eax, 0x20`
`xor eax, 0xAA`

`pop esi`
`ret`

Comment: To clarify, I've also tried changing the order of the xor and sub instructions to before the loop, but I'm still getting gibberish back. As far as I can tell the loop is reversing correctly with the rotate left instruction, and the other 24 bit of EDX are being left alone, however, I think my problem is with the subbing of EAX, and the char is being modified elsewhere, but I can't see any evidence of this happening in the registers or on my watch list beyond what already happens in EChars. Is it possible that the characters being passed through need to be reversed in some other fashion?

Comment: I managed to get it working, to clarify for any others who are having/working on a similar program, I modified the latter half the decryption routine to be:

<br/> 
`push esi
push ecx
mov  esi, eax
and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF
ror byte ptr[esi], 1
ror byte ptr[esi], 1
add byte ptr[esi], 1
mov ecx, [esi]
//all changed below here, everything above is same
pop eax
xor eax, 0xAA
sub eax, 0x20
and eax, 0xFF
x17 :
rol al, 1
dec ecx   
jnz x17
pop esi
ret`

(I have no idea how to format this so you'll have to do that yourself, sorry).

Thanks for the help everyone.